# How to return value from SOAP function to meteor method?

Tags: node.js, web-services, magento, meteor, soap

I have a Meteor method inside that am calling the soap function.

Meteor is executing all the statement before its getting the response from soap client.

So i am getting a result as undefined.

I want to promise the soap execution before executing other statements in the method.

```
createSoapConnection(){
    var Soap = require('soap');
    var url = 'https://xxxxxx/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl';
    var args = {username: 'xxxxxx', apiKey: 'xxxxxx'};
        let client = Soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
        let result = client.login(args, function(err, result) {
        let sessionId = result.loginReturn.$value;
         console.log(sessionId);
            return {
                conn: client,
                sessionId: sessionId
                };
            });
        }); 
}
```

I am calling this method by this meteor method.

```
addsoapmessage(){
        let a = Meteor.call("createSoapConnection");
        console.log(a);
}
```

In the console am getting undefined as a result. after that the session ID is getting printed. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
meteor add zardak:soap
```

Install this package in root of application folder. then try with those following codes.

```
var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
var args = {name: 'value'};

try {
  var client = Soap.createClient(url);
  var result = client.MyFunction(args);

 return result; // or send this result to the function where ever you want.
}
catch (err) {
  if(err.error === 'soap-creation') {
    console.log('SOAP Client creation failed');
  }
  else if (err.error === 'soap-method') {
    console.log('SOAP Method call failed');
  }

}
```

You can do any soap api calls with these functions. for more details visit : https://atmospherejs.com/zardak/soap

Comment: I'm having trouble importing this package. I've tried `import {Soap} from 'meteor/zardak:soap';` `import * as Soap from 'meteor/zardak:soap';` and `import Soap from 'meteor/zardak:soap';`. 
It's giving me an error that `Soap.createClient()` is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Meteor methods don't return anything. You can ask for a callback, which will fire when it's done, but the callback won't pass back a return value, only an error if it found one.

The best way to deal with this is to get the method to save the result in a collection, and rely on a subscription to let the client see it reactively.

Alternatively you can store the returned data in a server variable, which is then only accessible by the server code (but that might work, as other server methods might want to access the values.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a callback function in your meteor call

```
 let a = Meteor.call("createSoapConnection", function (error, result) {
                // display the error to the user and abort
                if (error)
                    console.error(error.reason);

                else {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
fuction(url,args)
{
   soap = Npm.require('soap');
   var createClient=Meteor.wrapAsync(soap.createClient,soap);
   var client=createClient(url);
   var finalFunc=Meteor.wrapAsync(client.youfunction,soap);
   var result=finalFunc(args);
   return result;
}
```